# Android - Contextual Action Bar Overlaps Tabs on Android L

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, contextual-action-bar

When I enter edit mode in my app on the Nexus 5 with Android L Developer Preview installed the Contextual Action Bar overlaps the tab bar.[image: cab_overlap_screenshot]

This doesn't happen on my LG L90 (with Android 4.4 installed). [image]

I think Android L attempts to hide the Action Bar when entering edit mode, but not the tabs.  Is there a way that I can preserve the Action Bar so that the CAB just overlays it?  How do I get the CAB background to be non-transparent?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe this issue covers the behaviour you're facing ; https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=673 . And best help I can offer you is patience, I'm afraid, until new L images become available.

Comment: Can confirm that this has been fixed for a future release.

Comment: Cool, when i get to the office I'll have to check it out